# gradle access global variable from function call not work

Tags: gradle

I am trying to access a global variable from a function as below:

```
def var = "hello"

def func() {
    println("func:" + var)
}

tasks.register('callme') {
    doLast {
        print("callme:" + var)
        func()
    }
}
```

gradle report error message:

```
> Task :callme FAILED
callme:hello
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/vagrant/work/gradle/build.gradle' line: 67

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':callme'.
> Could not get unknown property 'var' for root project 'demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

What's the proper way to access a global variable from a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

def are not visible to functions, you have pass the value to the function.
use ext. properties if you need it that way

```
ext.extVar = "ext-hello"
def strVar = "hello"
def func(String strVar) {
    println("func - def:" + strVar)
    println("func - ext:" + extVar)
}
println "from root "
func(strVar)
tasks.register('callme') {
    doLast {
        println("callme:" + strVar)
        func(strVar)
    }
}
--


from root 
func - def:hello
func - ext:ext-hello

> Task :callme
callme:hello
func - def:hello
func - ext:ext-hello
```